# Find number of objects in nested array with different query params

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Event array but can't figure out how to query into the 'guests' nested array and do two things.

1. count the number of guests
2. count the number of attended guests (marked 'Y')

   ```
   { _id: new ObjectId('1'),
     name: event1,
     guests: [
       {
         phone: +12222222222,
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 'Y'
       },
       {
         phone: +12344466666,
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 'Y'
       },
       { phone: +11234567890, 
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 
       },
       {
         phone: +14443332222,
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 'Y'
       },
       { phone: +19090909090, 
         _id: new ObjectId
         attended:
       }
     ],
   },

   { _id: new ObjectId('2'),
     name: event2,
     guests: [
       {
         phone: +11111111111,
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended:
       },
       {
         phone: +12222222222,
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 'Y'
       },
       { 
         phone: +133333333333, 
         _id: new ObjectId,
         attended: 'Y'
       }
     ],
   },
   ```

My code below is on its 20th iteration without getting any closer.

```
const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id);
```

Comment: To clarify, it appears you want to accomplish your goal with a mongoDB query and not use JavaScript on the results shown - right?

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn - I'd like to use mongoose if possible but would take either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MongoDB query, you can use `$size` for calculating the size of the array field and `$filter` to filter specific document(s) that matched the criteria in the projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: "1"
},
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 1,
  guests: 1,
  totalGuests: {
    $size: "$guests"
  },
  attendedGuests: {
    $size: {
      "$filter": {
        input: "$guests",
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$this.attended",
            "Y"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eyvKDATSmho)

Comment: Thank you @yongshun this is awesome. Dumb question.. how would I access "attendedGuests" or "totalGuests" out of the query? Also appreciate the link to the mongo playground - didn't know that existed.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I'm not using Mongoose before. The link reference I think could help in [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4771#issuecomment-265291355).

Answer (score 0):

Yong Shun helped above but didn't get 100% of the way -- here is the full answer in case anyone encounters something like this in the future:

```
module.exports.showEvent = async (req, res) => {
    const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id).populate('artist');
    const { guest_id } = req.cookies;
    let totalGuests = 0;
    let attendedGuests = 0;
    const eventData = await Event.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "_id": objectId(req.params.id)
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                name: 1,
                guests: 1,
                totalGuests: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$guests" }, then: { $size: "$guests" }, else: "NA" } },
                attendedGuests: {
                    $size: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$guests",
                            as: "guest",
                            cond: {
                                $and: [{
                                    $eq: ["$$guest.attended", "Y"]
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
    if (eventData && Array.isArray(eventData) && eventData.length > 0) {
        totalGuests = eventData[0].totalGuests;
        attendedGuests = eventData[0].attendedGuests;
    }
    if (!event) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Event');
        return res.redirect('/events');
    }
    res.render('events/show', { event, eventData });
    console.log(totalGuests, attendedGuests);
};
```